# Mac (or c++) connection to binary WCF

Tags: c++, objective-c, wcf, c#-4.0

I've got a WCF service being hosted using TCP/IP (netTcpBinding):

```
var baseWcfAddress = getWcfBaseUri();
host = new ServiceHost(wcfSingleton, baseWcfAddress);

var throttlingBehavior = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentCalls = Int32.MaxValue;
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentInstances = Int32.MaxValue;
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentSessions = Int32.MaxValue;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttlingBehavior);

host.Open();
```

I'd like to write a Mac client in Objective C or C++. Are there any existing classes that can facilitate the connection to my WCF service? If not, what are my steps & options to making it happen?

Comment: What is the reason for using netTcpBinding? I might have some suitable options...

Comment: `netTcpBinding` was found to be one of the quicker options -- certainly much faster than the vanilla BasicHttpBinding/WS binding that was tried. That's the only real need since netTcpBinding used binary vs straight text it was faster.

Comment: right; I suspected as much. Adding an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every binding starting with `net` is considered as not interoperable. Even pure .NET client without WCF is not able to communicate with the service without enormous effort by reimplementing whole binary protocol and encoding. You should probably start with:

- [.NET Message Framing protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219293%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx)
- [.NET Binary Format: XML Data Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219210%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx)

Your option for Mac is using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF) which should have support for netTcpBinding.

Your real option for Objective-C / C++ on Mac is creating interoperable WCF  service exposing data over HTTP. If you are not the owner of the service you can create routing WCF service which will be [bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667246.aspx) between interoperable HTTP and netTCP.

Edit:

One more thing - if the service uses `netTcpBinding` with default configuration it is secured with windows security. I expect that it can be another show stopper on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the comment:

> `netTcpBinding` was found to be one of the quicker options -- certainly much faster than the vanilla BasicHttpBinding/WS binding that was tried. That's the only real need since netTcpBinding used binary vs straight text it was faster.

Firstly, I have looked at this many, many times - and oddly enough, ***every*** time I test it, `NetTcpBinding` completely fails to be any quicker than the basic xml offering. However, since performance is your goal I have options...

I'm a bit biased (since I wrote it), but I strongly recommend "protobuf-net" here; since it is designed along the same idioms as most .NET serializers, it is pretty easy to swap in, but it is faster (CPU) and smaller (bandwitdh) in every test I make for this - or tests that [other people make](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.1000000-times.2010-02-06.html). And because the protobuf format is an open specification, you don't have to worry about the "Net" bindings being non-interoperable.

For MS .NET, I have direct WCF hooks that can be [used purely from config](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/controlling-wcf-protobuf-net-at.html) making enabling it a breeze. I honestly don't know how well that will work with the Mono equivalent - I haven't tried. It *might* work, but if not the other option is to simply throw a `byte[]` or `Stream` over the network and worry about (de)serialization manually.

My preferred layout here is basic-http binding with MTOM enabled, which gives you the simplicity and portability of the simplest xml binding, without the overhead of base-64 for the binary data.