# How can consume NetTcpBinding .NET webservice in iOs?

Tags: iphone, ios, wcf, web-services, nettcpbinding

I want to consume a webservice written in .NET from iPhone , it uses NetTcpBinding shows in wsdl. is it possible to consume webservice other than BasicHttpBinding from iphone?. If possible, How can i consume it?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consume service exposed by `netTcpBinding` only by WCF clients (= .net). Any other client needs enormous effort to make this work because you will have to [reimplement WCF's communication protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459619/mac-or-c-connection-to-binary-wcf/6459723#6459723).

Even `basicHttpBinding` is not very good choice because iPhone has poor support for SOAP (check link provided by @Franchesca). The best choice is using REST service exposing POX (simple XML) or JSON with `webHttpBinding` as mentioned by @Valery Pavlov.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info.

Answer (score 1):

i think no. you can use only serialized data transfer methods for cross-platform system interaction with service. you need to use xml or json serialization for that, with wcf service based on webHttpBinding.

Answer (score 0):

With WCF, it is possible to create your own [custom binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347793.aspx). You will of course have to write code on the iPhone side that can deserialize the messages etc. [Here is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-using-objective-c-on-iphone) relating to this topic that might be helpful for you to read.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use `ASP.NET Web API.`

Reference link
http://www.asp.net/web-api