# Sending custom WCF requests via Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets, tcp

I've seen a few questions left half-answered regarding this topic.
I want to send a request to my self hosted WCF application, which uses NetTcpBinding.
The problem is, I have to use sockets.

I've written a transport binding element which opens a TcpListener(on the ChannelListener OnOpen)
This works fine, but in that case - I'll have to use my own message framing model.

Obviously, I'm not going to implement the net.tcp message framing model( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff470920%28v=prot.10%29.aspx)

I've read a few posts(including http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/01/13/writing-custom-requests-to-simple-wcf-services.aspx) which suggest I should send a request and interpret the bytes sent via a MessageEncoder/MessageInspector.

This way, I can basically create a message for each of my methods/operations(with minor
changes per request)

I tried this method and I got the bytes in question(through the use of a custom MessageEncoder) when I used a WCF channel(from a ChannelFactory).

I've saved those bytes, and sent them through a TcpClient  - the MessageEncoder wouldn't fire up.

When I Open a normal channel:

```
        ChannelFactory<ITestService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(new    NetTcpBinding(),
            "net.tcp://localhost:76599");

        factory.CreateChannel().DoSomething(string.Empty); //gets to MessageEncoder
```

When I try the same via Sockets:

```
        TcpClient cli = new TcpClient("localhost", 76599);

        byte[] fileArray = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\fileFromMessageEncoder.bin");
        cli.GetStream().Write(fileArray, 0, fileArray.Length); // Does not get to MessageEncoder
```

any ideas?

Comment: There is one thing about your post that's not clear to me: why must you use sockets to communicate with your server? Also, if you must use sockets, why not just build a simple socket server? Understanding what's motivating your unusual requirements might help to find the best solution.

Comment: @PaulKeister
I have a few clients that already use my contract(through different wcf bindings) - I want other clients(who use c++, Java or Mono) to be able to connect to the same WCF app, so I could manage the requests without using my own framing model.  That way, I could send binary data(from the client, wrapped in the WCF Contract interface) which would fire up an operation, and then return my response through a Channel I would implement myself.  Thanks in advance for any solution you might think of :)

Comment: Obviously you could create a functional Java or Mono client fairly easily by adding an endpoint with a SOAP or REST binding (you can use WCF for (managed) C++ on Windows). As for a cross-platform implementation of NetTcp, it's interesting to note that there are some patent warnings from Microsoft on the links you've provided. Clearly, you're swimming upstream in a pretty fast current. See this question for some background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459619/mac-or-c-connection-to-binary-wcf/6459723#6459723

Comment: @PaulKeister using A SOAP or REST binding isn't relevant as I need
to use a tcp based transport for better performance.
My clients are developed by numerous developers outside my company, 
so I need to be able to provide a single interface they can work with.Creating an implementation of the exposed Contract, which builds the binary data used by net.tcp seems to be perfect solution.The reason I'm not rebuilding the net.tcp message framing model is to avoid issues with Microsoft. However, reading the bytes sent to a MessageEncoder and sending those same bytes from the clients seems logical.

Comment: And obviously I'm interested in a cross-platform implementation.
Managed clients currently use another WCF endpoint.
Thanks again :)

Comment: You have a good reason for desiring a binary protocol. However, if you want a cross-platform binary protocol, perhaps you should consider not using WCF. Although this would require quite a bit of effort, it is very likely, in my opion, to result is a safer and more maintainable solution than trying to re-implement a WCF NetTcp client on multiple platforms.

Comment: @PaulKeister I've already implemented a TCP Server(wrapped in my own binding with a custom Transport).Even if eventually I won't go with the solution I've suggested, the TCP server implementation is always there as a backup plan.I simply don't understand why the bytes I'm receiving through the MessageEncoder don't produce the same result when I'm sending them via the client application.I suspect there might be some kind of handshake/negotiation involved before those bytes are actually sent.I'll try having another look at the RFC and see if I can find anything useful. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work.
I initiated the default handshake for a Net.Tcp connection prior to sending the bytes I got via the MessageEncoder.

It's important to note that the endpoint uri must be UTF-8 encoded.

The process is pretty easy - send the negotiation request, send an End Preamble message(0x0C) and wait for the server to return a Preamble Ack message(0x0B).

Then you can send the binary envelope and recieve the response from the WCF application.

I hope this post could help someone in the future.

```
NegotiationConsts.Via via = new NegotiationConsts.Via(uri);
int arraySize = via.EndpointString.Length + 
NegotiationConsts.DefaultRequestLength;

byte[] request = new byte[arraySize];

int count = 0;
request[count++] = NegotiationConsts.Version.RECORD_TYPE;
request[count++] = NegotiationConsts.Version.MAJOR_VERSION;
request[count++] = NegotiationConsts.Version.MINOR_VERSION;

request[count++] = NegotiationConsts.Mode.RECORD_TYPE;
request[count++] = NegotiationConsts.Mode.DUPLEX;

request[count++] = NegotiationConsts.Via.RECORD_TYPE;
request[count++] = via.Length;
via.EndpointString.CopyTo(request,count);
count+=via.EndpointString.Length;

request[count++] = NegotiationConsts.WCFEncoding.RECORD_TYPE;
request[count++] = NegotiationConsts.WCFEncoding.BINARY_ENCODING;

return request;
```